# Android content provider random order

Tags: android, random, uri, android-contentprovider

Can someone point me in the right direction please:

How can i provide this query back in random order?

```
musiccursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
musicdata, 
selection,
dirs, 
MediaColumns.DATA+ " asc");
```

I have tried replacing "asc" with various things, including Random(), RAND....i'm stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, this is how i implemented the solution:

```
if(isShuffle){
// shuffle is on - play a random song
 sortOrder = "RANDOM()";
 } 
else{
sortOrder = MediaColumns.DATA+ " asc";   
}

...

//run the query          
musiccursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
musicdata, 
selection,
dirs,
sortOrder);
```

By doing this I can throw a randomly ordered cursor to a list view.  The user gets to see the random play list order, rather than just randomly selecting the next song "in secret" that most apps do.

Answer (score 2):

Select 25 random records:

```
musiccursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
musicdata, 
selection,
dirs, 
"RANDOM() LIMIT 25");
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Ah nice, thanks for that.  How would i ensure that random was set high enough for the entire set?  Would i have to pass through it twice?.

Comment: Glad you answered your other concern, for our app we wanted to support shuffle but not risk loading to much data at a time, so we select 25 random records at a time and when we run out run another select, if you are doing something similar (shuffle) something like this could be a good option.

Comment: That's food for thought Ian.  What's the cost of the overhead of just randomizing a full list rather than doing it your way?  I assume you are thinking about memory useage?

Comment: I think this depends on how many songs the user has on their device, it was memory usage I was concerned about. I am making the assumption here that you are selecting songs, forgive me if I am wrong.

Comment: Its a tablet app.  left side is folders list, middle is files list, and right is player controls.  I'm shuffling the middle list, the files.  There could potentially be thousands on this list.

Comment: Right, I suppose you can only really try it and see if it performs well, my scenario was very different.